# get location of script requiring current script

Tags: node.js

I need to do some file operations with paths relative to the script that required the current one.

Say we have the following in `~/somewhere/file2.js`

```
const y = require('~/file1.js');
```

And in `~/file1.js` we have:

```
const x = require('./other/script.js'); //relative to ~/file1.js
```

And we invoke it like this:

```
cd ~/somedir
node ~/somewhere/file2.js
```

then within `~/other/script.js` we can do this:

```
console.log(__dirname);         // -> ~/other
console.log(__filename);        // -> ~/other/script.js
console.log(process.cwd());     // -> ~/somedir
console.log(process.argv[0]);   // -> path/to/node
console.log(path.resolve('.')); // -> ~/somedir
console.log(process.argv[1]);   // -> ~/somewhere/file2.js
```

None of these are the path I need.

How, from `~other/script.js`, can I determine the location of the script that required us - i.e `~/file1.js`

To put it another way.
`~/somewhere/file2.js` requires `~/file1.js`
and 
`~/file1.js` requires `~/other/script.js`
from within `~/other/script.js` I need to do file operations relative to `~/somewhere/file1.js` - how can I get it's location?

I actually only need the directory in which `file1.js` sits, so filename or directory will work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `module.parent.filename` inside of `other/script.js`, or you can pass the `__dirname` as a  parameter to your module like `require('other/script.js')(__dirname)` (given your module exports a function)

Comment: `path.dirname(module.parent.filename)` sounds like exactly what I need, thanks.
Although a word of warning to others finding this - the path given will be that of the _first_ module to include this one. In my scenario there is only one, but if you have multiple then this approach may not be suitable.